# Keep the inner text using the title inside the tag

Tags: javascript

Having a tag like this:

```
<h1> Title</h1>
```

What kind of DOM comman should someone use to keep the inner text of the h1 tag which inside it contains the Title text.

Example like this command:

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1')
```

Comment: So you want the "Title" of H1 using DOM?

Comment: You could convert NodeList to array and filter by text content `[...document.querySelectorAll('h1')].filter(item => item.textContent.includes('Title'))`

Comment: @keidakida yes that's it

Comment: then you can do this `document.querySelectorAll("h1")[0].innerText`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you

Answer (score 1):

That command in your question returns a list, so index the first element and get the inner text, like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1")[0].innerText
```